# Flash - offline - multiple users

Tags: flash

I want to make a flash which shows actual information of co-workers (at desk, coffe-break, etc). Problem is that I have no server-side support (big company, no sense of humor etc). So there's an "offline" shared html (with the embedded swf), and if someone changes his/her status everybody should see it. I'm looking forward any solution (eg some kind of refresh button which calls the actual info).

Thank you!
YvorL

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to store server data without a server. Flash cannot interact with filesystem, unless it is an AIR application. So unless you have an underlying PHP (or any other actually) server/local server it is impossible, as far as I can tell at least.

Comment: Yep, I thought it's kinda impossible, but if there's a txt file which stores the data, could it be possible? I got info that in AS3 it's possible to export data without server.

Comment: In FlashPlayer 10.0c and later you can use FileReference to select file and then you can put into that file whatever you want. However though it is still the user who has to select this file manually using Open/Save file dialog.